# Jquery Modal Dialog Only Draggable 1 Time

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a jquery modal form that is opened by a button click. I have left the default for draggable (true), but for some reason, it won't drag again after dropping it. I can move it one time, but after I let it go, it won't move again.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $("div#newSenderDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        title: "New Template Sender",
        modal: true,
        position: {top: 50, left: 20},
        buttons: {
                Cancel: function (){$(this).dialog('close');}
            }
    });
$("button#new").click(function(){
    $("div#newSenderDialog").dialog('open');
});
</script>
<div id='newSenderDialog'>
<form id='newSender'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <span class='formElement'><input type='text' name='senderEmail' /></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Campus</label>
            <span class='formElement'><?php echo $view->GetUniversity()->GetCampusSelect('senderCampus', '', GetSessionVar('campusid', '1', 'managedTemplates'))?></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have two dialogs on the page, and both are having this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried your example (minus the PHP) and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/2rJ4K/ Have you checked you have no repeated IDs ?

Comment: I have tried in both IE10 and FF 21

Comment: The fiddle I posted works for me on IE 9, FF20 & Chrome 26

Comment: Yea, it works for me also, the problem is definitely not with the modal dialog that I made, but I was hoping that someone might know what to look for that would cause this kind of behavior

Comment: When you say you have 2 dialogs in the same page I wonder if they have (by mistake) the same id? where is the code to the other dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It had to do with unregistering events with .off() after an event fired. That unregistered the event that draggable needed after drop.